# Is it possible to minimize this summation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am given the following information:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = 1$$
$$\forall i \in n \quad a_i > 0$$
I would like to minimize the following summation:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2$$
I don't really know where to begin.  Or if such a thing is even possible.  I believe the answer is: $$\forall i \in n \quad a_i = \frac{1}{n}$$
But I am not sure.

If calculating this is possible, does anybody know the procedure (or name of procedure) for minimizing the above summation?

Thank you.

Comment: The answer seems correct to me. But you must change $\forall i \in n$ by $0 < i \le n$.

Comment: Ah whoops, misread the question, sorry

Comment: One general method that you can use on such problems is the method of [Lagrange multiplies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i\right)^2\leq\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i^2\right)$$
$$\text{if }b_i=1$$
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\right)^2\leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\right)\cdot n$$
$$\therefore \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i^2\geq\frac{1}{n}$$
The minimum is $\frac{1}{n}$, which happens when vector $a$ and vector $b$ are parallel, which means all $a_i$'s are same, i.e.
$$a_i=\frac{1}{n}$$
as you expected.